# Trouble with SimpleXMLElement Namespaces

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm having trouble parsing XML with Namespaces using SimpleXMLElement.

I've tried using looping through the xml and also tried using xpath without success.

```php
$data_url="http://isni.oclc.nl/sru/0000000123121970?query=pica.isn+%3D+%220000000123121970%22&version=1.1&operation=searchRetrieve&stylesheet=http%3A%2F%2Fisni.oclc.nl%2Fsru%2FDB%3D1.2%2F%3Fxsl%3DsearchRetrieveResponse&recordSchema=isni-b&maximumRecords=10&startRecord=1&recordPacking=xml&sortKeys=none&x-info-5-mg-requestGroupings=none";
$data = file_get_contents($data_url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

$org_names = $xml->children('srw', true)->records->children('srw', true)->record->children('srw', true)->recordData->responseRecord->isniassigned->isnimetadata->identity->organisation->organisationnamevariant->mainname;

foreach($org_names as $a) 
{
  echo "a: $a\n";
}
```

I'm expecting to get a list of organisationnamevariant->mainname items:

```
Academia lugduno-batava
Leiden university
Leidse universiteit
etc.
```

However, I'm getting this error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: You've got your object->property chain about 15 levels deep there. Try splitting it up so you know which one is triggering the error. How do you know namespaces have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: Please could you [edit] your question to include a small XML document in the question itself? As it is, if the content of that link changes, the question won't be of any use to future readers with similar problems, because they won't be able to see what you were trying to do.

Comment: Also, remember that the prefix assigned to namespaces (e.g. `'srw'`) can change without changing the meaning of the document; for instance, if the system generating the XML switches to a different library that assigns prefixes differently. It's best to rely instead on the actual namespace URI, giving it a name in your code for easy reference (e.g. `const NS_SRW = 'http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/';`)

Answer (score 1):

Having such a deep hierarchy is difficult to navigate using the normal `->` structure, but you also have to be careful when changing namespace.  You only need to do the `->children('srw', true)` once and then all of the child nodes will be for that namespace.  BUT you also have to switch back at `<responseRecord>` by using `->children()`.

You also need to be careful that you use the proper case for each tag name...

```
$org_names = $xml->children('srw', true)->records->record->recordData->children()->
       responseRecord->ISNIAssigned->ISNIMetadata->identity->organisation->
       organisationNameVariant->mainName;

echo (string)$org_names;
```

An alternative is to use XPath (as `xpath()` returns a list of matches, I use `[0]` to only use the first one)...

```
$org_names = $xml->xpath("//organisationNameVariant/mainName");

echo (string)$org_names[0];
```

I know that `echo` casts the value to a string, but if you use this in any other scenario, you may end up with a SimpleXMLElement instead, so I tend to add the case to string in just to make the point.

Comment: Ah, thank you Nigel. I didn't know I needed to switch back. And thank you for pointing out the case sensitivity - I was just trying lower case to try a different solution.